# Callback function in menu items field

Tags: routes

Is it possible to put callback function here `$items['callback?']` ? I need to change this field every time when user make some changes. The biggest problem for me is that `hook_menu()` is cached and menu is rarely updating.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use a function to return an array of menu router items but practically it will not work because of caching.

However you can register wildcats paths like companies/*so your page callback will be fired on every companies/* pages.

To do so, set the key of the $items like this:

$items['companies/%'] = array(...menu router info here ...);